# Differentiate between close reasons in terms of required votes when displaying close-voters

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I agreed with SevenSidedDie's Argument, that the question [What does thieves' cant sound like?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102177/what-does-thieves-cant-sound-like) is off-topic because it asks for the sound of an existing language/slang and thus belongs to another SE and I voted to close it (as off-topic).

But I clearly disagreed with the reason that it is opinion-based (because it is a real thing). Now when you look at it, it displays my name as I would have voted for it being opinion-based.

While I do not see it that harsh, I would say that it is basically misquoting.

So I ask for a system, where the close system waits for 5 close votes for the same reason, or which shows clearly when some user closed it because of a different reason.

Comment: Requested on [meta.se] already (and gets suggested *a lot*): [show each voter's close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/152515). I *sincerely* doubt slowing down closure for a full 5-vote alignment on one reason is ever going to occur -- if five or more close voters think a question needs to be closed, it ought to get closed, whatever the reasons they had.

Comment: That request exists 7 years to the day and still, it hasn't got implemented. So, I guess I'll have to get along with being misquoted.

Comment: I'd be interested to know where you live because being misquoted isn't illegal in most English speaking parts of the world (i.e. those with a common law tradition) unless it amounts to defamation

Comment: I might have misinterpreted it, (edited it out) but the page I found when I searched for it, basically said that claiming someone said sth he didnt is a violation of the general law of personality.